# Why is flex box not working as expected in my code?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I started writing this code with HTML, not finish though, but expected the navbar to align horizontally to them, but this isn't working. I'm a beginner at coding.

I was expecting the navbar to appear at the top of the page but it somehow was aligned to the left.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;600&family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap');
/* !BASE STYLES/RESET */
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root{
    --light-color: #f3f3fe;
    --dark-color: #363636;
    --border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    --link-hover-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    --title-font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'serif';
    --body-font-family: 'Poppins', 'sans-serif';
    --container-padding: 1.5rem;
    --section-vertical-spacing: 8rem;
}
html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body{
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--dark-color);
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
body.dark-theme{
    --light-color: #000;
    --dark-color: #fff;
    --border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: none;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
i{
    font-size: 2.4rem;

}
input,
button,
textarea{
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
/* !HEADER */
.header{
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
/* !navbar */
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NGAYU'S WEBSITE</title>
    <!-- !BOX ICONS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    <!-- !SCROLL REVEAL -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.0/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <!-- !MY STYLESHEET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- !HEADER -->
    <header class="header" id="home">
        <nav class="navbar container">
            <a href="./index.html" class="logo">Ngayu</a>
            <div class="navbar-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="button icon-button menu-toggle-button">
                    <i class="bx bx-menu open-icon"></i>
                    <i class="bx bx-x close-icon"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="button icon-button theme-toggle-button">
                    <i class="bx bx-toggle-left theme-off"></i>
                    <i class="bx bx-toggle-right theme-on"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">
                            <span>01</span> About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">
                            <span>02</span> Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">
                            <span>03</span> Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if it is due to a typo delete the question

Comment: it is invalid CSS, your editor should flag this

Comment: Dear @rioV8, Please may I know why it is invalid CSS? I'm a beginner and I don't know much. Please help tell me why it's invalid. My editor didn't flag anything.

Comment: using `*` selectors is very bad for performance, enumerate all the tags you use

Comment: I have added the `}` and now the snippet looks a lot more of what you want, press the `Run` button

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the closing curly bracket in `.header`

Comment: Dear Nikolas Cocci, Even after typing in the curly bracket, it still didn't give me the required result.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the three items at the right, add this CSS rule to have them in one line (the default for flex items is to arrange them horizontally):

```
.menu > .list {
  display: flex;
}
```

If you need to create some distance between them, add (for example) this, which will create a left margin for each of the menu items:

```
.menu > .list > .list-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;600&family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap');
/* !BASE STYLES/RESET */
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root{
    --light-color: #f3f3fe;
    --dark-color: #363636;
    --border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    --link-hover-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    --title-font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'serif';
    --body-font-family: 'Poppins', 'sans-serif';
    --container-padding: 1.5rem;
    --section-vertical-spacing: 8rem;
}
html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body{
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--dark-color);
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
body.dark-theme{
    --light-color: #000;
    --dark-color: #fff;
    --border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: none;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
i{
    font-size: 2.4rem;

}
input,
button,
textarea{
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
/* !HEADER */
.header{
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
/* !navbar */
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}
.menu > .list {
  display: flex;
}
.menu > .list > .list-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NGAYU'S WEBSITE</title>
    <!-- !BOX ICONS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    <!-- !SCROLL REVEAL -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.0/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <!-- !MY STYLESHEET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- !HEADER -->
    <header class="header" id="home">
        <nav class="navbar container">
            <a href="./index.html" class="logo">Ngayu</a>
            <div class="navbar-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="button icon-button menu-toggle-button">
                    <i class="bx bx-menu open-icon"></i>
                    <i class="bx bx-x close-icon"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="button icon-button theme-toggle-button">
                    <i class="bx bx-toggle-left theme-off"></i>
                    <i class="bx bx-toggle-right theme-on"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">
                            <span>01</span> About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">
                            <span>02</span> Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">
                            <span>03</span> Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```